# What is the score function formula of sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-mining, cross-validation

I know that `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score` function use a `make_scorer()` function which returns a callable that scores an estimator’s output. 
What is the scoring function that is used in `cross_val_score()`function ?
I guess it's one of the below choices:

- accuracy_score
- mean_squared_error
- adjusted_rand_index
- average_precision

Comment: There are a few scoring options in sklearn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the scoring that you choose. See the possible list of options here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter

Also, as written here in section 3.1.1,
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html,

"By default, the score computed at each CV iteration is the score method of the estimator. It is possible to change this by using the scoring parameter."

Comment: For Classification estimators, it is `'accuracy'`, for other types it may change according to estimator.